# Hibernate multiple Many To many relation with the same class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I got a problem with hibernate and mapping multiple objects of the same type, maybe im just stupid.

I have an Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

  @Id
  private int id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<LanguageBasedText> name;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<LanguageBasedText> longDesc;

 (...)
}
```

and the Language Based Text

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "languageBasedText")
public class LanguageBasedText {

  @EmbeddedId
  private LanguageTextEmbeddedKey embeddedID;

  @Column(name = "text")
  private String text;

}
```

with an embedded Key

```
@Embeddable
public class LanguageTextEmbeddedKey implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "productID")
  private int productID;
  @Column(name = "lang")
  private String lang;
  @Column(name = "type")
  private String type; 
  //i get the type from an other source and it is the information where 
  //the text goes (name or longDesc or 100 other posibil multi 
  //language text fields)
}
```

the question ist: How do i get hibernate to map this right

i want a table like

TEXT

product_id | lang | type | text

and

PRODUCT

product_id | some other stuff |

Comment: You start by realizing this is actually a question about the standard JPA API and not HIbernate specifically. And if I read the question correctly, the actual question you're asking is how to use a ManyToMany mapping when an EmbeddedID is involved?

Comment: im not shure if that is the actual question seems like the part with multiple many to many mappings for the same class would be ignored. But if you know a easy way to realise it in an easy way tell me how you would do it :)

Comment: I can't be of help when you don't know what question you're actually asking. At best I can link to the standard JPA documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html

Comment: Did either of the answers below help? If so please consider [accepting one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Summary: You don't actually want many-to-many, you want one-to-many with inheritance (using the Single-Table-Per-Hierarchy strategy) on the many side, or a filter on the OneToMany properties using `@Where`. The former approach is possibly "more OO", the latter is less typing and potentially prevents class explosion if you have many different i18n text fields. Both `@DiscriminatorOptions` and `@Where`are hibernate annotations, so you have strayed outside standard JPA annotations either way.

#### The Model

If you think about the `ManyToMany` approach you can see that without a filter to specify a `type='name'` criteria, `name` could pull back a `longDesc` text as well as a `name` text for the same language - which can't be right. So if you apply a filter then you now have `OneToMany` as you only have one `name` per `{productID, lang}`.

If you think of this in pure modelling terms:

- one `Product` can have many `Name`s, but only one name per `lang`;
- so each `Name` is unique for the candidate key `{ProductId, Lang}`;
- and the same is then true of `LongDesc`;
- You can therefore view `Name` and `LongDesc` as separate business entities.

This is therefore a `OneToMany` model for each of the `LanguageBasedText` properties in `Product`. `Name`, `LongDesc` (and other similar properties you allude to) just happen to share the same properties: they implement the same interface so storing them in one table with a discriminator is possible.

**Inheritance strategies**

You can take advantage of the common interface for the text entities and implement an inheritance strategy. In your case, with a discriminator column, you jumped ahead and are naturally using a Single-Table-Per-Hierarchy inheritance model. In your code you effectively have:

```
public abstract class LanguageBasedText {}
public class NameText extends LanguageBasedText {}
public class LongDescText extends LanguageBasedText {}
public class Product {
  private Set<NameText> names;
  private Set<LongDescText> longDescs;
}
```

#### The code

Expressing this with JPA & making it work with Hibernate:

1. Create the root entity type, usually as `abstract` and `@Entity` to prevent it being stored directly. Specify the `@Table` for clarity, along with the `@DiscriminatorFormula`.
2. Also add `@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)` - this solves an issue with loading the wrong types into the i18n properties in `Product`
3. Inherit that in `@Entity` classes such as `NameText extends LanguageBasedText`.
4. Add the `@OneToMany` properties into Product, typed as collections parameterized for the text class subtype (e.g. `Set<NameText>`).

And in code:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    private Product() {}
    public Product(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    // omitting the other properties
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<NameText> name = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<LongDescText> longDesc = new HashSet<>();

    private String sku;
    ...
}

@Embeddable public class LanguageTextEmbeddedKey implements Serializable {
    private LanguageTextEmbeddedKey(){}
    public LanguageTextEmbeddedKey(int productID, String lang, String type) {
        this.productID = productID;
        this.lang = lang;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Column(name = "productID") private int productID;
    @Column(name = "lang") private String lang;
    @Column(name = "type") private String type;
    ...
}

@Entity @Table(name = "languageBasedText")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula(value="type")
@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public abstract class LanguageBasedText {   
    @EmbeddedId private LanguageTextEmbeddedKey embeddedID;
    @ManyToOne() @JoinColumn(name="productID", insertable=false,updatable=false, nullable=false)
    protected Product p;
    private String text;

    protected LanguageBasedText(){}
    protected LanguageBasedText(int productID, String lang, String type, String text) {
        this.embeddedID = new LanguageTextEmbeddedKey(productID, lang, type);
        this.text = text;
    }
    ... 
}

@Entity @DiscriminatorValue("name")
public class NameText extends LanguageBasedText {
    private NameText(){}
    public NameText(int productID, String lang, String text) {
        super(productID, lang, "name", text);
    }
}
// similarly for LongDescText
```

N.B. There is a lot of other (less relevant) code missing from the above, including the mandatory no-args ctors on all types, mutators/accessors etc.. I have also used `productID` in the ctors for the text classes, but I would recommend you replace those ctors with DDD methods such as `addNameText` to encapsulate that id.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, the associations in `Product` are not `@ManyToMany`. A `LanguageBasedText` Entity can only refer to one `Product`, therefore the associations in `Product` must be `@OneToMany`.

But, what I think you are trying to achieve is to have the `name` list in `Product` contain the list of `LanguageBasedText` objects that refer to that `Product` and have a `Type` of "name". And the `longDesc` list should contain the `LanguageBasedText` objects that have the `type` of "longDesc".

Since you are using Hibernate, the easiest solution for that would be to use the `@Where` annotation on the `@OneToMany` lists, thus in `Product` you would have:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Where(clause="type='name'")
private List<LanguageBasedText> names;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Where(clause="type='longDesc'")
private List<LanguageBasedText> longDescs;
```

Notice I also changed your lists to be plurals, as that makes more sense (in English).

Another (more complex) solution would be to use inheritance and define sub-classes of `LanguageBasedText` for each type, using a single table strategy and with the `type` column as the discriminator value. Thus you would have sub-classes like:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("name")
public class NameLanguageBasedText {
    ... etc
```

But you would end up with hundreds of these sub-classes, and I'm not sure how the discriminator column would work being in an Embedded Id.

Comment: Can you please provide a more details about your first solution? I tried but hibernate creates separated tables for each relation, and type column has null values. Can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry, I'm in the middle of a big project with tight deadlines, so I can't afford the time to give you a more specific example. I'm not sure that Hibernate can use the @Where for creating the sub-records. Have you tried googling for a specific example? You are probably looking at the my second, more complex solution which is using mapped sub-classes, but that depends on how many types you might have.